# javascript get a query string that a form will submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, selenium

If you have a form, like

```
<form id='testform' method="post" action="/" />
  <input name="test1" value="yes" type="text">
  <input name="test2" value="no" type="text">
</form>
```

Is there a way to get the query string that this form would submit? (without knowing anything about what fields are inside it)  `test1=yes&test2=no` or just the same thing in json format?

I am using selenium, so could do it either on the selenium side run javascript in the browser.

```
const form = await driver.findElement(By.id('testform'));
.. now do something in selenium to find out the request post request
```

or in the browser

```
const form = document.getElementById('testform');
... somehow get the query string or request info
```

any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually need the string of data or just to send it somewhere, eg through ajax? If the latter you can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to grab all of a form's input fields and send through ajax directly

Comment: Do you want just a string from all input fields `name-value` pairs?

Comment: yeah - string, or object

Comment: I'm need it in selenium, but so if selenium had a way to do it that would be best, but if there is a way to get it in the browser, I can just use `executeScript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Patrick,

```
const formFields = await driver.executeScript('return Array.from(new FormData(document.getElementById("testform")))');
```

works great.

I guess if anybody needs to do this without selenium it's just

```
Array.from(new FormData(document.getElementById("testform")))
```

or look at the other ways you can cycle through the `FormData` object.

Then you can turn that into a query string if that is what you need.